# Theme of codinghorror.com

Tags: themes

I liked theme of codinghorror.com . It's Typepad theme but i need wordpress theme of this. Where i can find it ? Best regards, Dreamer

Comment: Voted to close as off topic. We're not here to help you steal somebody's theme.

Comment: Maybe we should be kinder with noobs, he's obviously not expressed himself correctly, but reads like a theme recommendation.

Comment: I never called anyone a thief, but i'll admit my last comment was perhaps a little unthoughtful of me, and have thus removed it.

Comment: Great, I deleted my comment referring to yours too. That was great, we all make mistakes, but we learn by recognizing them. With actions like this we're creating a great community and making this site an awesome place to hang around with WP questions :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually i'm pretty sure it's Movable Type. And honestly, it's about as simple a theme as you could find.

If I were you, I'd start with the [Thematic](http://themeshaper.com/thematic/) framework and add a tiny bit of CSS. Shouldn't need much more than that!

Answer (score 3):

The codinghorror.com theme is probably a custom one. You should search the [WordPress themes directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) which has some search filters for a similar one. Once you find a relatively similar one, you can modify it to look similar to Mr. Atwood's blog.

It's pretty minimalist, so you shouldn't have much trouble implementing a similar theme yourself.

Take in consideration you can't use the logo image, Coding Horror is using it with permission from the original author. Check the bottom of the Coding Horror page for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Rather than just ripping the design (as described below), you might consider *asking*  Jeff if he is OK with this. He might say yes, in which case you can feel good about yourself (as opposed to feeling all slimy and dirty :-).

It's also possible to grab the source of one of the rendered pages and use that as a starting point for converting a static design to a WP theme. There is a *very* good tutorial on going static => theme by Chris Conyiers. It's at Lynda.com and so costs $, about $25 for 1 month. I found it extremely interesting. (I have no connection with either Chris or Lynda).

*Update for comment about the availability of "free tutorials":*

I have been a professional programmer for more than 3 decades, and my time is worth money. I have just recently moved into the WP universe so that I can offer a lower cost option to my smaller customers. For the last 4 years I have worked almost exclusively in Django, one of the most amazingly well-documented OSS projects on the planet. As I have tried to come up to speed on current best practices in the world of WordPress, I have been appalled at the haphazard, incomplete, inconsistent, woefully out of date, and just plain *bad* documentation. At times it feels like I am wading through a swamp.

Almost all of the tutorials I have seen on the subject of converting static HTML to a working WP theme have failed to deliver the "whole product." Chris's 4 hours of video instruction delivers a near-complete, detailed description of how to go from concept to Photoshop to static HTML/CSS to skeleton theme to fully instrumented theme, all of it accompanied by an excellent running commentary about *why* he took certain paths and not others. It's not perfect, but it is head an shoulders above whatever is in second place.

I am a programmer, not a designer, and I gained several valuable insights into the end-to-end process. I have a designer I work with and she is most definitely *not* a programmer. She watched the same 4 hour tutorial and *also* gained several valuable insights. We both bill at $100/hour and this was worth *way* more than 15 minutes of our time. BTW, another source of consistently excellent info on WP (theme development and a whole lot more) is [Justin Tadlock's blog](http://justintadlock.com/).

Comment: There are about a million tutorials posted all over the web on how to turn astatic css to wp theme for free

Comment: I hear you on _quality_ of WP documentation and tutorials. :( I read few blogs about WP and hang around here a lot for that very reason.

Comment: NetTuts has some good tutorialsm including on converting static to WP